# SwiftUI - How to create matrix or grid of colored Squares

Tags: matrix, swiftui, grid, layer

i have started to learn SwiftUI and i would like to create a matrix of colors.
I created that with UIViews and Controllers before using layers, in a way that i would calculate width and height of pixel

```
        onePixelHeight = mainView.bounds.height/CGFloat(rows*graphicMultplikator)
        onePixelWidth = mainView.bounds.width/CGFloat(columns*graphicMultplikator)
```

than add empty layers to UIView:

```
for i in 0...(rows*graphicMultplikator)-1
    {
        for j in 0...(columns*graphicMultplikator)-1
        {
            addEmptyLayerToMainView(i:i,j:j)
        }
    }
```

like this:

```
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x:CGFloat(j)*onePixelWidth, y: CGFloat(i)*onePixelHeight, width: CGFloat(onePixelWidth),height: CGFloat(onePixelHeight))
        layerP.append(layer)
        mainView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

and later fill every layer with needed color:

```
var counter = 0
for i in 0...(rows*graphicMultplikator)-1
    {
        for j in 0...(columns*graphicMultplikator)-1
        {
            let squareColor = TermoColor().getScaleColor(value: matrix[i][j])
            layerP[counter].backgroundColor =  squareColor.cgColor
            counter += 1
        }
    }
```

[example of desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQvBu.png)

I am creating matrix of size 96x96.
So i would like to create same thing using SwiftUI but i haven't find solution yet, if someone can help me i would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

this is 2 attempts i made, first is using lazyVGrid but it's slowing layout when it's trying to appear:

```
struct MatrixMapping: View {
var rows: Int
var columns: Int


var colors: [Color] = [.blue, .yellow, .green]

let gridItems = Array(repeating: GridItem(.adaptive(minimum:0.1), spacing: 0), count: 96)

var body: some View {

    LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach((0..<(96)), id: \.self) { index in
                Text("")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0.1, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0.1, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(colors[index % colors.count])
                    .padding(0)
            
            }
            .padding(0)
        }
    .padding(0)
    }
}
```

second is lighter on memory and is doing what i want at first but i can't figure out if i can change colors of every square and in project i need to change colors dynamically every second, so i need to pass matrix every second or so and it should change colors of every square based on my calculations.

this is second attempt:

```
struct MatrixMapping: Shape {
let rows: Int
let columns: Int

func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()

    // figure out how big each row/column needs to be
    let rowSize = rect.height / CGFloat(rows)
    let columnSize = rect.width / CGFloat(columns)

    // loop over all rows and columns, making alternating squares colored
    for row in 0 ..< rows {
        for column in 0 ..< columns {
            if (row + column).isMultiple(of: 2) {
                // this square should be colored; add a rectangle here
                let startX = columnSize * CGFloat(column)
                let startY = rowSize * CGFloat(row)

                let rect = CGRect(x: startX, y: startY, width: columnSize, height: rowSize)


                path.addRect(rect)
            }
        }
    }

    return path
}
```

}

and i call it like this:

```
 MatrixElement(rows: 16, columns: 16)
                .fill(Color.black)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.  Look into `LazyVGrid` and `LazyHGrid` that might get you started. When you have an attempt we can help you workout the kinks if you have any.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i updated original post